# Multiple Regex in a single lines

Tags: php, regex

It is quite interesting for me to work on this Regex. I have a list of a string containing few lines. Lets say

```
$ingredients = '--For Salad ~20 mins~
1 1/2 Cup warm water (105°F-115°F)
2 1/4 Teaspoon active dry yeast
1 Cup packed dark brown sugar
2 tbsp Finely chopped garlic
1 tbsp Tabasco
--For Marination ~35 mins~
3 tbsp Fresh lime juice
1 tbsp Fresh orange juice
1 tbsp Dijon mustard
1 tsp Curry powder, toasted
1/2 teaspoon salt
1/4 teaspoon black pepper
1/2 cup olive oil ';

$list = explode("\n", $ingredients);

foreach ($list as $key => $data)
{
    $data = preg_replace('/^\s*\-{2}(.*)/', '<h4>$1</h4>', $data);
    $pos = strpos($data, '<h4>');
    if ($pos === false)
    {
        echo '<span class="name">' . $data . '</span>';
    } else
    {
        echo $data;
    }
}
```

How do I match the another pattern and replace that with other elements and append inside of another string replacement.

In the first line with a string starting with double hyphens contains a parameter starting and ending with Tilde `~`.

What I want is to get other patterns for each line and output it.

The output I want to look like below.

```
<h4>For Salad  <span class="duration">20 mins</span></h4>
<span class="name">1 1/2 Cup warm water (105°F-115°F)</span>
<span class="name">2 1/4 Teaspoon active dry yeast</span>
<span class="name">1 Cup packed dark brown sugar</span>
<span class="name">2 tbsp Ffinely chopped garlic</span>
<span class="name">1 tbsp Tabasco</span>
<h4>For Marination <span class="duration">35 mins</span></h4>
<span class="name">3 tbsp Fresh lime juice</span>
<span class="name">1 tbsp Fresh orange juice</span>
<span class="name">1 tbsp Dijon mustard</span>
<span class="name">1 tsp Curry powder, toasted</span>
<span class="name">1/2 teaspoon salt</span>
<span class="name">1/4 teaspoon black pepper</span>
<span class="name">1/2 cup olive oil </span>
```

Another output am trying is to fetch that h4 as separate with those other patterns.

```
<h4>For Salad</h4><span class="duration">20 mins</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you out, Here we are searching for `~` and replace `~([^~]+)~` with `span` tags around it.

> **1.** `~([^~]+)~` this will match all the characters in between `~`'s including `~`'s

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785452)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$ingredients = '--For Salad ~20 mins~
1 1/2 Cup warm water (105°F-115°F)
2 1/4 Teaspoon active dry yeast
1 Cup packed dark brown sugar
2 tbsp Ffinely chopped garlic
1 tbsp Tabasco
--For Marination ~35 mins~
3 tbsp Fresh lime juice
1 tbsp Fresh orange juice
1 tbsp Dijon mustard
1 tsp Curry powder, toasted
1/2 teaspoon salt
1/4 teaspoon black pepper
1/2 cup olive oil ';

$list = explode("\n", $ingredients);

foreach ($list as $key => $data)
{
    $data = preg_replace('/^\s*\-{2}(.*)/', '<h4>$1</h4>', $data);
    $pos = strpos($data, '~');
    if ($pos !== false)
    {
        echo $data = preg_replace("/~([^~]+)~/", '<span class="duration">$1</span>', $data);
    } 
    else
    {
        //replacing data with span tags around it
        echo $data = str_replace($data, '<span class="name">'.$data.'</span>', $data);
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Solution 2:**(`another format`)  [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785547)

```
foreach ($list as $key => $data)
{
    if (preg_match('/^\s*\-{2}([^~]+)(~[^~]+~)/', $data,$matches) && strpos($data, '~') !== false)
    {
        echo "<h4>".$matches[1]."</h4>";
        echo '<span class="duration">'.$matches[2].'</span>';
    } 
    else
    {
        //replacing data with span tags around it
        echo $data = str_replace($data, '<span class="name">'.$data.'</span>', $data);
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: span element appears inside the h4 element. It has to appear after the h4 end tag.

Comment: I am trying that in a list loop and now. you can check here as i used @casimirs code in above comment but something is wrong with list item each has to be listed in separate li. Your code seems to be working and its good replacement in 1 shot as you said but listing that each step in a separate is quite difficult or am i doing a mistake? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7f01da04d714c61e20715f368733f956f5edc5a

Comment: @Maqk I have updated my post hope this will help you out for the second type of format you want

Answer (score 2):

I will do that in one shot with `preg_replace_callback` without exploding:

```
$display = preg_replace_callback('/^\h*(?:--([^\n~]+)~([^\n~]+)~|([^\r\n]+))/m', function ($m) {
    return isset($m[3]) ? '<span class="name">' . $m[3] . '</span>'
                        : '<h4>' . $m[1] . '<span class="duration">' . $m[2] . '</span></h4>';
}, $ingredients);

echo $display;
```

[demo](https://eval.in/785460)

The idea is to build a pattern for the two kinds of line, then the callback function has only to know which branch has matched testing the capture groups to return the good replacement.

Comment: Your code seems to be working and its good replacement in 1 shot as you said but listing that each step in a separate is quite difficult or am i doing a mistake? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7f01da04d714c61e20715f368733f956f5edc5a

Answer (score 1):

Try deciding what what to do with each line before you replace anything:

```
foreach ($list as $key => $data)
{
    $matches = [];
    if (preg_match('/^--(.*)~(.*)~$/', $data, $matches) {
        echo '<h4>' . $matches[1] . '</h4>' .
             '<span class="duration">' . $matches[2] . '</span>';
    } else {
        echo '<span class="name">' . $data . '</span>';
    }
}
```